# How can I pin the *compilation* buffer to never leave a single frame/window

Tags: window, frames, compilation

I would prefer to have the `*compilation*` buffer always stay in its own frame. However, currently if I run `M-x compile` from another frame/window, the buffer pops up in a new window there as well. How can I cause emacs to instead only raise the existing frame which is displaying the `*compilation*` buffer?

Comment: I believe this is the answer to your question, which I wrote up 3 years ago at the beginning of my Emacs quest:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19415289/2112489  The applicable sections of code in `compile.el` may have changed, and I have since made many changes/improvements to my custom functions that target certain frames for buffer display:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame  Take a look and see if the first link is approximately what you are seeking -- who knows, it may even still work without making changes.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, Emacs considers the selected frame the only reusable frame.
In other words, normally Emacs only searches the current ("selected") frame for windows that already contain the buffer-to-display ("reusable windows"). What you need is for Emacs to consider the compilation buffer's frame as a reusable frame:

```lisp
(push '("\\*compilation\\*" . (nil (reusable-frames . t))) display-buffer-alist)
```

The above snippet will make all the frames reusable when `display-buffer` displays the `*compilation*` buffer. Look at the documentation of `display-buffer-reuse-window` to learn what other values `reusable-frames` can receive.

However, this doesn't take care of the other direction - opening a code buffer from the compilation window. For example, if you open a buffer by pressing a link in the compilation buffer, Emacs will open the buffer in the same frame as the compilation window. Changing that is another matter. I don't know how the behavior compares with the `special-display-buffer-names` solution.

Answer (score 5):

Make buffer *compilation* always have a dedicated window. One way to do this is to customize option `special-display-buffer-names`, to include `"*compilation*"`. Another is to customize option `special-display-regexps`, to include a regexp that matches that buffer name. (I include the regexp `"[ ]?[*][^*]+[*]"`, which matches all buffers whose names are `*...*`.)

(See also option `special-display-frame-alist`, which you can use to specify the behavior and characteristics of the frame used for such special-display buffers.)

Emacs will tell you that these "special-display buffer" options are "obsolete", but thank goodness they are still supported. They offer a simple way to do what you want.

If you want to suffer through what Emacs prefers you do now, then customize option `display-buffer-alist` instead. The idea is essentially the same (it's just an uglier and more complicated user option).

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes? Is there something incorrect in this answer?

Comment: It's probably for the obsolete options and the snark ("suffer").

Comment: This works very well, and except for the feature being obsolete it exactly solves OP's (and my ;) ) requirement. Selecting an error line in the *compilation* buffer correctly displays the source file in another frame, not in the special *compilation* frame. Really a shame, especially since the "official" way described in the other answer doesn't have a solution for this aspect, and also references to `special-display-buffer...`.

Comment: @user227: Nothing snarky about that *"suffer"*. If you use `display-buffer-alist` then you'll know what I mean. I think most, if not all, users lament how complicated it is. I think even its designer does, but nothing simpler yet just as flexible has been uncovered yet. Special-display is great (IMHO) for the simple cases it handles - it does that well. I don't think that feature should be obsolete just because we *also* need something general like `display-buffer-alist`.